# How to use intrinsic functions !sub method in Aws cdk?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I want to use this resource below for my cdk app, I using Python for CDK:

```
'arn:aws:s3:::${LoggingBucket}/AWSLogs/${AWSAccoutID}/*'
```

Therefore I need to substitute the value of `LoggingBucket` and `AWSAccountID`.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(self, "my-bucket", bucket_name = 'my-bucket')

core.Fn.sub('arn:aws:s3:::${LoggingBucket}/AWSLogs/${AWSAccoutID}/*',[bucket.bucket_name, core.Environment.account])
```

**But I get this error for line of `core.Fn.sub` :**

```
AttributeError: type object 'property' has no attribute '__jsii_type__'
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

**Then I tried this as well:**

```
mappings = {
    'LoggingBucket': bucket.bucket_name,
    'AWSAccountID': core.Environment.account
}

core.Fn.sub('arn:aws:s3:::${LoggingBucket}/AWSLogs/${AWSAccoutID}/*',mappings)
```

> $ cdk synth

I still getting the same error as above.

**Question:**

Please give me a solution on how to use the !sub function in cloudformation in CDK. Let me know what I doing wrong as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Python (or other programming language) there is no need to use the instrinsic functions that Cloudformation provides.

I suggest a more elegant and easy way to format the arn:

```
arn= f'arn:aws:s3:::{bucket.bucket_name}/AWSLogs/{core.Environment.account}/*'
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using regular python when creating your infrastructure using AWS CDK you can use python's built-in 'format' method:

```
'arn:aws:s3:::{}/AWSLogs/{}/*'.format(bucket.bucket_name, core.Environment.account)
```

or using the old way of python string formatting

```
'arn:aws:s3:::%s/AWSLogs/%s/*' % (bucket.bucket_name, core.Environment.account)
```